# ajax beforeSend not working when sending formData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a div

that shows a loader image while sending ajax requests

I attached the div in the beforeSend attribute of ajax. The issue is if I send serialize() data then the beforeSend works but doesn't work when I send formData

Works

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'centre-basic-process.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#centreform').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.displayLoader').show();
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#centreformupload').show();
        $('#centreform').hide();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Doesn't work

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'centre-upload-process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.displayLoader').show();
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert("You have succesfully submitted the form. Please complete the payment method");
        document.location.href = "dashboard.php";
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

I even tried `ajaxStart()` but facing same issue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which version of Jquery you use ?

Comment: @ShadyAtef jquery1.9.1

Comment: @PrateekVerma formData contains images ..which is processed using PHP in backend

Comment: Can you put a live example on websites like [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: @ShadyAtef how do i do that...the form is processed using php in backend

Comment: But the problem is in the front side.. not the back side.. I want to see what happens in the front end only ..

Comment: @PrateekVerma I wrote this.....is it ok?? var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

Comment: @ShadyAtef https://jsbin.com/zolenaralo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It is ok, but then also, you can try it by taking it in another variable just like this: var form = $('#centreform')[0];

Comment: And then in another variable :  var formData = new FormData(form);